# Powershell CommandNotFoundException is terminating?

Tags: powershell

When executing such a script:

```
nonexistingcommand
echo "Hello"
```

I get:

```
nonexistingcommand : The term 'nonexistingcommand' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Playground\powershell\Test.ps1:2 char:1
+ nonexistingcommand
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nonexistingcommand:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
Hello
```

So it seems that the `CommandNotFoundException` is a non-terminating error. So why if I

```
try {
 nonexistingcommand
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException] {
  throw
}
echo "Hello"
```

In this case, it will exit and not print "Hello".

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, PowerShell has *two* types of *terminating* errors:

- *Statement*-terminating errors, which by default only terminate the enclosing *statement*.

  - By default, execution *resumes*, namely with the *next* statement (`echo "Hello"` in your case)
  - `CommandNotFoundException` is an instance of such an error.
  - By contrast, *non*-terminating errors continue processing even of the originating statement, if further pipeline input is available (e.g., `Get-ChildItem NoSuchDir, \` emits a non-terminating error for non-existing dir. `NoSuchDir`, then goes on to successfully report on existing dir. `\`)
- *Script*-terminating (thread-terminating) errors, which terminate the enclosing *script and the entire call stack*.

  - Such errors are triggered by the [`throw` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw) called *from PowerShell code*, never by *binary* (compiled) cmdlets.

---

The [`try { ... } catch { ... } finally { ... }` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) does *not* distinguish between these two subtypes: it catches them *both*.

- Given that your `catch` block contains an argument-less `throw` statement, which implicitly relays the error that triggering error, you're effectively turning the *statement*-terminating error into a *script*-terminating one, so execution ends there.

Similarly, setting the [`$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference) to `'Stop'` causes *all* types of errors (emitted by *PowerShell* commands<sup>[1]</sup>), including *non*-terminating ones, to abort execution overall; in other words: both *non*-terminating and *statement*-terminating errors are promoted to *script*-terminating ones.

---

For a **comprehensive overview of PowerShell's surprisingly complex error handling**, see [GitHub docs issue #1583](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).

---

<sup>[1] At least in local, foreground invocations of *external programs* in consoles (terminals), *stderr* output is by default *not* routed via PowerShell's error stream, and therefore not affected by `$ErrorActionPreference`.

However, in PowerShell v7.1 and below, including in Windows PowerShell, using a `2>` redirection *does* route stderr through PowerShell's error stream, which can have unexpected side effect. This problem will be fixed in v7.2.

Note that the behavior is PowerShell *host-specific* and applies to host `ConsoleHost` (use `$host` to get host information). *Other hosts* still *invariably* route stderr via the error stream, which notably affects *remoting* and *background jobs*.</sup>

Comment: 1. Can you supply an example to a non-terminating error (not even a _statement-terminating_ one? 2.What do you mean  by "stderr output is not routed via Powershell's error stream"? If I `cmd /c "echo STDERR 1>&2" 2>&1` Powershell recongnizes this as an error..?

Comment: @YoavKlein: Re 1: I've added an example to the answer. Re 2: Please see the updated footnote. In short, _by default_ it doesn't go through the error stream, but in v7.1- it does _with `2>`_, which is a problem that will be fixed in v7.2 (preview versions already have the fix). _Other hosts_ (other than `ConsoleHost`; use `$host.Name`) - which notably affects remoting and background jobs - still _invariably_ route stderr via the error stream , unfortunately.

Comment: You mean that if I run a command and then `2>` then the STDERR of the program _does_ go through the error stream? Actually, not only when I'm using `2>` it seems that it does, also when `$output=some_command` the STDERR of `some_command` isn't included in $output

Comment: @YoavKlein, yes, that's what I meant. That `$output = ...` captures only the _success_ output stream (which _stdout_ maps to in external-program calls) is by design (just like it is only success output that flows through the pipeline). You can do `$output = cmd /c "echo STDOUT & echo STDERR 1>&2" 2>&1` to capture both stdout and stderr.

Comment: @mkelment0, what I'm trying to understand is: You say that by default, an external program's STDERR is not routed to Powershell's error stream, but on the other hand, it is also not routed to the Success stream (since it's not included in the `$output`) - then where is it routed to? Sure enough it is displayed on the screen..

Comment: @YoavKlein, indeed, stderr is passed straight through to the display (terminal) by  the `ConsoleHost` host - unless redirected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237373/discussion-between-yoavklein-and-mklement0).

Answer (score 0):

The above error that states command was not found is a terminating error. When such an error is encountered, powershell pipeline stops execution. Only the statements within catch block are executed.

To know the difference between terminating and non-terminating errors, checkout this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-terminating-and-non-terminating-errors-in-powershell

If some statements are to be executed even if you encounter a terminating error, specify them within finally:

```
try {
 nonexistingcommand
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException] {
  throw
}
finally {
  echo "Hello"
}
```

The above will print `Hello`

Comment: The question isn't primarily about `try`, it is about why combining `try` with `throw` in the `catch` block _aborts the script as a whole_, whereas _not_ catching the terminating error _continues execution_.

Comment: yea, i didnt give much focus to this part i guess: `terminating and non-terminating errors`